# AnkhSVN ignore pattern

Tags: svn, ankhsvn, svnignore

How does AnkhSVN keep non-versioned files out of SVN? I checked the global ignore pattern and the svn:ignore property but found nothing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Project implementations provide a list of files that should be added to source control as part of their SCC support. AnkhSVN 2.0 captures this list (and registers to several events to receive changes), so it doesn't use a specific pattern.

Implementing patterns would make AnkhSVN project type specific, while the Visual Studio SDK allows everybody to create their own project type. We used to have smart patterns when AnkhSVN add-in in 0.X/1.X, but as SCC VAPI implementation we don't have to guess any more.

When AnkhSVN has this list it checks the not-added files for subversion ignore status (Global ignore pattern and svn:ignore on the directory) and suggests the files that are not ignored as 'new' (aka Should be added).

Comment: Salute! Thanks for this marvellous tool.